# Wings are not interacting with the object?

Tags: modifiers, cloth-simulation, collision

I have this character and as you can see the wings do not interact with the hive. I have collision and cloth on the wings, I created a vertex group and went to cloth-shape-pin group wings, but the wings still do not work? Is there a better way to get these to interact?

[image]

blend: [image]

Comment: pls provide blend file so we can check it out. tx

Comment: i posted the blend file

Comment: In the blend file you provide the objects don't have cloth or collision, but if you give them physics it seems to kind of work, you need to subdivide your wings though, also maybeit would be better to animate with some bones to fake the effect?

Comment: Setting a rigid-body physics with the "animated" box checked for the wings and rigid-body physics at default for the hive kind of works. But the hive bounces around because it's colliding with the wings and the bee can't exactly get out without the hive stuck on its winds. xD. But as Moonboots said, it might be better to sprinkle a bit of fakery in there with a simple rig.

Comment: thanks for the reply , true though , u guys were right , i think the simpliest solution for this was just a simple rig , what i did is actually added a simple shape keys and it worked lol , thanks moonboots the best , e3 production